# "Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration error" in storybook

Tags: typescript, webpack, storybook, tsconfig, webpack-5

I have an alias in `paths` in main `tsconfig.json` but it does not work with `"@nrwl/storybook": "^13.1.4"` and webpack `5.37.0`. I got an error when I try to import module:

```
ERROR in ./libs/design-system/theme/src/provider.tsx 4:0-58
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@libs/shared/feature-platform' in '/Users/project/libs/design-system/theme/src'
resolve '@libs/shared/feature-platform' in '/Users/project/libs/design-system/theme/src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/project/package.json (relative path: ./libs/design-system/theme/src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/project/libs/design-system/theme/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/project/libs/design-system/theme/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/project/libs/design-system/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/project/libs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/project/node_modules
        /Users/project/node_modules/@libs/shared doesn't exist
      /Users/project/Sources/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/project/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

Resolve configuration in storybook's webpack:

```
{
  extensions: [
    '.mjs', '.js',
    '.jsx', '.ts',
    '.tsx', '.json',
    '.cjs'
  ],
  modules: [ 'node_modules' ],
  mainFields: [ 'browser', 'module', 'main' ],
  alias: {
    '@storybook/addons': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/addons',
    '@storybook/api': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/api',
    '@storybook/channels': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/channels',
    '@storybook/channel-postmessage': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/channel-postmessage',
    '@storybook/components': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/components',
    '@storybook/core-events': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/core-events',
    '@storybook/router': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/router',
    '@storybook/theming': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/theming',
    '@storybook/semver': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/semver',
    '@storybook/client-api': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/client-api',
    '@storybook/client-logger': '/Users/project/node_modules/@storybook/client-logger',
    react: '/Users/project/node_modules/react',
    'react-dom': '/Users/project/node_modules/react-dom'
  },
  fallback: {
    path: '/Users/project/node_modules/path-browserify/index.js',
    assert: '/Users/project/node_modules/browser-assert/lib/assert.js',
    crypto: false
  },
  plugins: [
    TsconfigPathsPlugin {
      source: 'described-resolve',
      target: 'resolve',
      extensions: [Array],
      log: [Object],
      baseUrl: '../../../',
      absoluteBaseUrl: '/Users/project/',
      matchPath: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2021",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "cypress",
      "node",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
"@libs/shared/feature-platform": [
        "libs/shared/feature-platform/src/index.ts"
      ],
}}
```

What can be wrong?